# Getting specific character values from argv[] and making a new const char

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, cs50

I am certain this has been answered before, but I cannot wrap my head around the answers. I am doing an entry C course and there is a provided header, cs50.h, that has the string type in it. So while I have been using it, I am not quite sure how it works.

My goal is to get the characters at **argv[1][0]** and **argv[1][1]** into a **const char *variable**. While I know the answer definitely involves pointers and addresses, I have not been able to find the successful combination. I am asking here in hope that someone can show me the right way with my own code so I can learn how to go about it.

**UPDATE** I am trying to get the first two char characters from the second (i.e. first string that isn't the file name) thus, **argv[1][0]** and **argv[1][1]** So the given input will be something like this helloworld and I just want 'h' and 'e'. I do not know how to combine 'h' and 'e' from the argv array into a const char *variable, which is the requested format I need to pass it to another function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    string saltget[2] = { &argv[1][0] , &argv[1][1] };
    printf("%s\n", saltget);

}
```

Comment: `string saltget = (char[]){ argv[1][0] , argv[1][1], 0 };` (I think type of `string` is `char *`, not `const char *`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[1][0]` is of type `char`, so if you wish to construct a string with this character as first letter, it would be:

```
char str [] = {argv[1][0], argv[1][1], '\0'};
```

---

Please note that hiding pointers behind a typedef is very bad practice, so you should avoid the cs50 library, as it teaches this bad practice. They define "string" as `typedef char *string;`. And while the pointer hiding is bad, the name `string` is even worse, as the name collides with C++ `std::string` and there will therefore be much confusion for the reader when they see the code.

Comment: @moooeeeep See [DESCRIPTION](https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_string)

Comment: Hah. So simple. This is literally the only idea I hadn't tried. Thank you for the advice and help!

Comment: Indeed, tell your professor that the professional community on Stack Overflow discourages his `string` type. We have seen many (conceptual) errors by students using the type.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to convert `argv[1][0] and argv[1][1]` instead of `argv[1][0] and argv[2][0]`? I think this code will work for `argv[1][0] and argv[1][1]`.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])//argv[1] = hello argv[2] = world
{

    const char* saltget[2] = { &argv[1][0] , &argv[1][1] };
    printf("%s\n", saltget[0]);//hello
    printf("%s\n", saltget[1]);//ello

}
```

If you want to convert `argv[1][0] and argv[2][0]`, you can simply change `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` to `int main(int argc, const char* argv[])`

Comment: The OP mentioned that they want the characters, not the whole strings.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your fast reply. I updated the question to make it more clear. @Lundin is right.

Comment: It is my pleasure:) @user2853325